# dApp registration issue - Shiden Network

Tags: astar, validation, address, apps

I'm in the process of making a video tutorial for The Kusamarian YouTube channel :"How to register a dApp on Shiden Network"

I went through all the steps, but it failed at the end.

Could you please tell me what's wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to be whitelisted to be able to join dApp staking:
Please check the requirements here: https://docs.astar.network/docs/dapp-staking/for-devs/requirements

Please contact me on Astar Discord if you need more information (Maarten).